# Define solid $B$ by $x^2 + y^2 \leq z^4$ ,where $0 \leq z \leq 1$. The volume of the solid is:

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Apparently the answer is $\dfrac{\pi}{5}$, but I have no idea how a $\pi$ even gets in there.

I first tried drawing it out, and getting my triple integral's limits. They gave me $z \in [0, 1]$, then looking at the equation I plugged in $0$ for $z$ to get the 2D limits for $x$ and $y$, solved and got
$$
x \leq \sqrt{-y^2}
$$
and
$$
y \leq \sqrt{-x^2}. 
$$

I looked up a ton, but maybe I'm just not looking up the right thing or I don't know. How on earth do I get the integration bounds/limits for this $x$ and $y$? Also, If possible how do I get the $\dfrac{\pi}{5}$ answer?

Comment: Convert $(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ to $(2\pi r^2 rdr)$

Comment: Why do we convert $(x^2 + y^2)dydy$ to $2pir^2rdr?$ 
Are you saying that this is the equation of a circle? $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ where $z^2$ is r?

Comment: Consider an infinitesimal strip of the solid at a height z with length dz, then the volume of this strip can be approximated by a cylinder to be $\pi z^4dz$. All you need to do is integrate this from limits $z =0$ to $z = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Integrate in cylindrical coordinates

$$V=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1(1- z)r dr d\theta
= 2\pi \int_0^1 (1- \sqrt r ) rdr=\frac\pi5$$

Comment: How are you getting the radius from 0 to 1 and the 1-z in the integrand? shouldn't z be from 0 to 1?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle - the volume projection onto the $xy$-plane is a circle of radius 1, hence from 0 to 1, and $1-z$ is the integrand in cylindrical integration.

Comment: How did you know that it's a cylinder? Also how did you get the XY plane? I tried to get the traze but that just left me with $x^2 + y^2 = 0$

Comment: @TizzleRizzle - at $z=1$, you get $x^2+y^2=1$. In cylindrical coordinates, the integrand $1-z$ is the difference between the upper and lower surfaces.

Comment: ohhhh I see for the radius part! Is there any theory behind the 1-z being the distance between upper and lower surfaces? Is it just that since z is our height we go to the top of z and subtract it from the point z to get our length? similar to taking the integral of two lines?

Comment: @TizzleRizzle - correct